# Python utf-8 decoding

Tags: python, encryption, utf-8, cryptography

I'm having a problem with a task for my classes. The program is supposed to have two inputs - the first one beeing the text to decipher, and the second one being the key, and it should use the one pad cipher with XOR method. The thing is the entire text is encoded in hex (f.e \x04\x00\x00). I've managed to get it working pretty decently, but I can't get it to decode some symbols - "é" and "–". At this point I'm pretty much stuck on this. Here's the code:

```
    itemsList=[]

while True: #this is just the way of reading both key and text, it's all done on an online platform and it has to be done this way
    try:
        line=input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    itemsList.append(line)

cryptogram=itemsList[0]
key=itemsList[1]

decodedCode=bytes(cryptogram,"utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
decodedKey=bytes(key,"utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")

decodedCodeList=[]
decodedKeyList=[]

for letter in decodedCode:
    decodedCodeList.append(ord(letter))

for letter in decodedKey:
    decodedKeyList.append(ord(letter))

result =[]

if len(decodedCodeList)<len(decodedKeyList):
    longest=len(decodedCodeList)
else:
    longest=len(decodedKeyList)

for index in range (0, longest):
    result.append(decodedCodeList[index]^decodedKeyList[index])

resultToAscii=""

for item in result:
    resultToAscii+=chr(item)

finalResult=""
for item in resultToAscii:

    finalResult+=item

finalResult=bytes(finalResult,"unicode_escape").decode("utf-8")

print(finalResult)
```

The result's I'm getting are f.e "They state 1784\xe2\x80\x931834: the." and I should be getting "They state 1784–1834: the." or "\xc3\xa9tage" instead of "étage". I've found that it might have to do with latin symbols encoding, I've tried decoding it using "latin1" but with no result.
I've also tried :

```
print(repr(bytes(result))[2:-1])
```

Instead of:

```
resultToAscii=""

for item in result:
    resultToAscii+=chr(item)

finalResult=""
for item in resultToAscii:

    finalResult+=item

finalResult=bytes(finalResult,"unicode_escape").decode("utf-8")

print(finalResult)
```

But even more symbols were wrongly decoded.

Comment: Why `unicode_escape` ? But in general: it seems you are confusing what your are doing. Comment in your code the input and output in different part: what it is binary encrypted, what binary decrypted (utf-8), and what it is text. I think you are confusing, Do encryption on binary level (0-255), else  the encryption and decryption will not be binjective (so unique)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share example(s) of `cryptogram` and `key` strings supplied to `input()` as well as current and expected output…